# Find where string fails in specified format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a string that must look like

> ```
> [[12.12345678,12.12345678],[12.12345678,12.12345678],[12.12345678,12.12345678],..]
> ```

That is it looks like a `list of list`. But at times this string has corruptions that looks like this

> ```
> [12.12[12.12345678,12.12345678],
> ```

Another such case

> ```
> [21.28211533,21.22[21.28211517,84.13454000],
> ```

An extra `[12.12` can be seen in the first example. There may be other formats by which its failing too.

Currently, I'm using `ast.literal_eval` to check if it's in the `list of lists` format

```
import pandas as pd
import ast
import sys

df = pd.read_csv("whole.csv", sep = ";")
_ = 1
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    try:
        ast.literal_eval(row["gnns_base_lat_long"])
        _ += 1
        print("\rSuccessful %d" % _, end="")
    except:
        _ += 1
        print("Fail %d" % _)
        print(row["gnns_base_lat_long"])
print("\n")

sys.exit(0)
```

How to write a script such that if `ast.literal_eval` fails I go into this string to find how it failed?

An example output would be

> ```
> Fail: [12.12[12.12345678,12.12345678],
> ```

[File](https://pastebin.com/LqKdtFMu) with sample data. Its a download-able csv file. Use `";"` as the delimiter.

It would be great if I could get a **generalized answer** which prints all the cases it fails (ie it's not a `list of list`)

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Comment: @asongtoruin I've edited the question to attach a file.

Comment: Make the file open to public or use a service like pastebin or paste a sample as part of the question.

Comment: Edited to point to a pastebin file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string into a list at the '],[' then test for square brackets in each part, if one is found print offending part + the 2 square brackets.

```
string =str('[[12.12345678,12.12345678],[12.12[12.12345678,12.12345678], 
[12.12345678,12.12345678]]')
string = string[1:-1]
string = string.split(",")
x = 0
fl = 0
for i in string :
    b = (string[x])
    c = 0
    detect = 0
    for i in range(len(b)):
        d = (b[c])
        if d=='[':
            detect += 1
        c += 1
    if detect == 2:
        if fl == 0:
            print(string[x]+']')
        else:
            print('['+string[x])
    x += 1
    if fl == 0:
        fl = 1
    else:
        fl = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def check_string(s):
    for item in s.split(','):
        if item.count('[') > 1:
            print(item, s.index(item))
            return False
    return True

with open('data.csv') as file_obj:
    lines = file_obj.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        check_string(line[1:-1])
```

Output:

```
[21.28[21.28033850 1326
[21.93[21.28210850 1482
[21.03[21.28184083 0
```

A shorter version of Jack's answer. This will exit on the first occurrence of a bad string. If you need all the bad string locations, remove return statements.